# Can I use "lighterweight"?

Tags: comparatives

The word "lightweight" simply means, "relatively light in weight." If I want to compare two lightweight objects, can I say:

> Is A lighterweight than B?

Dictionaries don't seem to accept this as a word but would a native speaker be confused or annoyed by it? If so, which alternative would be most appropriate:

> Is A lighter weight than B?
>
> Is A more lightweight than B?
>
> Is A lighter-weight than B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can not. I'm not sure why, but that just sounds weird and abrasive to me.  Acceptable alternatives would include:

> Is A lighter than B?
>
> Is A more lightweight than B?
>
> Which is in the lighter weight class, A or B?

Answer (score 4):

This, of your three choices would be correct: **"Is A more lightweight than B?"**

If you look up the meaning and usage of **"lightweight"**, as shown here...

> light·weight /ˈlītˌwāt/ noun (from Google dictionary)
>
> **noun**: lightweight; noun: light-weight
>
> 1. a weight in boxing and other sports intermediate between featherweight and welterweight. In the amateur boxing scale it ranges
>      from 125 to 132 pounds (57 to 60 kg).
>
> • a lightweight boxer or other competitor.
>
> **plural noun**: lightweights; plural noun: light-weights
>
> 1. a person or thing that is lightly built or constructed.
>
> • a person of little importance or influence, esp. in a particular
>   sphere.
>
> "he was regarded as a political lightweight"
>
> **adjective**: lightweight; adjective: light-weight
>
> 1. of thin material or build and weighing less than average.
>
> "a lightweight gray suit"
>
> 1. containing little serious matter.
>
> "the newspaper is lightweight and trivial"

..."lightweight" is a noun or an adjective.  In your first example: **"Is A lighterweight than B?"**, your combined word "lighterweight" does not make sense.  Since it, like "lightweight" would be a noun or adjective, try replace it with a noun or adjective to test for accuracy. Would either of these sentences make sense to you?

> **Is A book than B?**   or   **"Is A awesome than B?"**

What you want to know is whether or not A weighs less than B so you must keep "lighter" and "weight" separate as their own words:

> **"Is A lighter weight than B?"**, or as you already proposed, **"Is A more lightweight than B?"**, making "lightweight" an adjective in that example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be understood with no problem, but I would not recommend it.

I'd go with something like

> Does A weigh less than B?

Comment: 'Lightweight' is also used in a metaphorical sense, when the comparative and superlative are allowed (at least by Wiktionary): Adjective
**lightweight** (comparative _more lightweight_, superlative _most lightweight_) (1) Lacking in earnestness, ability, or profundity [or gravitas].

Comment: @Edwin - Precisely so. A more lightweight book doesn't necessarily have fewer pages.

Comment: @j.R. Most of _my_ books have lots of pages. And lots of nice pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The comparative suffix cannot be "embedded" into a compound word.

> *light* + *weight* = single-word *lightweight*.

Also, avoid declensions using the *-er* suffix in case of words longer than three syllables or so.

*lighter*
*heavier*
*brighter*
*darker*

*easier*, but ***more*** difficult (*difficulter)
*simpler*, but ***more*** complex (*complexer)